# Are there any good image-manipulating APIs (ImageMagick alternatives) for PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gif

My host (wooservers) does not have ImageMagick installed on their shared servers so I was wondering if there was any image manipulation library/plugin I could use?

(Mainly to watermark GIF animations.)

As the only way I've found to watermark GIF animations was through ImageMagick

My host does not have ImageMagick installed on their shared servers. So I was wondering if there was any other way to use ImageMagick-like capabilities to watermark animated GIFs?

(Maybe like a web-service that allows me to send them the image with specifications on how to process the image, and they do the processing and I get my image back? Something of that sort? Which I believe is called an API?)

Comment: The simplest is to use GD :)
And a good option is to use some php library like Imagine for manipulating images :) They support GD/ImageMagick and others php libs for manipulating images https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Svetlio how does one install Imagine? I don't have ssh access, so I do not have access to the terminal. (Because I have shared hosting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just switched webhosts, that supported ssh terminal access and ImageMagick.
Thanks

Comment: hilarious, but honestly the best answer :D

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io) .  It's one of the best PHP image libraries I've used and can utilize both GD and Imagick as drivers.

Per the documentation, you can create watermarks like so:

```
// create new Intervention Image
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// paste another image
$img->insert('public/bar.png');

// create a new Image instance for inserting
$watermark = Image::make('public/watermark.png');
$img->insert($watermark, 'center');

// insert watermark at bottom-right corner with 10px offset
$img->insert('public/watermark.png', 'bottom-right', 10, 10);
```

Comment: Seems more up-to-date and community-supported, than other answers

Answer (score 2):

try **zebra-image**

> [**LINK HERE**](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-image/)

this is very easy to use and stabile for development

---

**Enjoy :)**

Answer (score 0):

Try [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/). It's pretty easy to use.